# Unable to run systemc program

Tags: software-installation

I have tried to run the systemc through vs code on my virtual box, then i realized that i need to install systemc-2.3.3.tar.gz but i am facing several issues. I am new to ubuntu. If you feel this is a silly question, please excuse me.
I got to know that configure.log file helps in figuring out the solution, but i dont know how. So im attaching the log file.

````
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by SystemC configure 2.3.3, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure 

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = radhe-VirtualBox
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 5.4.0-47-generic
uname -s = Linux
uname -v = #51-Ubuntu SMP Fri Sep 4 19:50:52 UTC 2020

/usr/bin/uname -p = x86_64
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = x86_64
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /usr/local/sbin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/games
PATH: /usr/local/games
PATH: /snap/bin


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2376: checking build system type
configure:2390: result: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
configure:2410: checking host system type
configure:2423: result: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
configure:2443: checking target system type
configure:2456: result: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
configure:2499: checking for a BSD-compatible install
configure:2567: result: /usr/bin/install -c
configure:2578: checking whether build environment is sane
configure:2633: result: yes
configure:2782: checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p
configure:2821: result: /usr/bin/mkdir -p
configure:2828: checking for gawk
configure:2858: result: no
configure:2828: checking for mawk
configure:2844: found /usr/bin/mawk
configure:2855: result: mawk
configure:2866: checking whether make sets $(MAKE)
configure:2892: result: no
configure:2917: checking whether make supports nested variables
configure:2934: result: no
configure:3004: checking how to create a pax tar archive
configure:3015: tar --version
tar (GNU tar) 1.30
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by John Gilmore and Jay Fenlason.
configure:3018: $? = 0
configure:3058: tardir=conftest.dir && eval tar --format=posix -chf - "$tardir" >conftest.tar
configure:3061: $? = 0
configure:3065: tar -xf - <conftest.tar
configure:3068: $? = 0
configure:3070: cat conftest.dir/file
GrepMe
configure:3073: $? = 0
configure:3086: result: gnutar
configure:3147: checking whether make supports nested variables
configure:3164: result: no
configure:3238: checking for g++
configure:3268: result: no
configure:3238: checking for c++
configure:3268: result: no
configure:3238: checking for gpp
configure:3268: result: no
configure:3238: checking for aCC
configure:3268: result: no
configure:3238: checking for CC
configure:3268: result: no
configure:3238: checking for cxx
configure:3268: result: no
configure:3238: checking for cc++
configure:3268: result: no
configure:3238: checking for cl.exe
configure:3268: result: no
configure:3238: checking for FCC
configure:3268: result: no
configure:3238: checking for KCC
configure:3268: result: no
configure:3238: checking for RCC
configure:3268: result: no
configure:3238: checking for xlC_r
configure:3268: result: no
configure:3238: checking for xlC
configure:3268: result: no
configure:3292: checking for C++ compiler version
configure:3301: g++ --version >&5
./configure: line 3303: g++: command not found
configure:3312: $? = 127
configure:3301: g++ -v >&5
./configure: line 3303: g++: command not found
configure:3312: $? = 127
configure:3301: g++ -V >&5
./configure: line 3303: g++: command not found
configure:3312: $? = 127
configure:3301: g++ -qversion >&5
./configure: line 3303: g++: command not found
configure:3312: $? = 127
configure:3332: checking whether the C++ compiler works
configure:3354: g++    conftest.cpp  >&5
./configure: line 3356: g++: command not found
configure:3358: $? = 127
configure:3396: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "SystemC"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "systemc"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "2.3.3"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "SystemC 2.3.3"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "http://forums.accellera.org/forum/9-systemc/"
| #define PACKAGE_URL "http://accellera.org/"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:3401: error: in `/home/radhe/Downloads/systemc-2.3.3':
configure:3403: error: C++ compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_build=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
ac_cv_env_CCASFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CCASFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CCAS_set=
ac_cv_env_CCAS_value=
ac_cv_env_CCC_set=
ac_cv_env_CCC_value=
ac_cv_env_CC_set=
ac_cv_env_CC_value=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXCPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXCPP_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CXX_set=
ac_cv_env_CXX_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_host=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
ac_cv_path_install='/usr/bin/install -c'
ac_cv_path_mkdir=/usr/bin/mkdir
ac_cv_prog_AWK=mawk
ac_cv_prog_make_make_set=no
ac_cv_target=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
am_cv_make_support_nested_variables=no
am_cv_prog_tar_pax=gnutar

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

ACLOCAL='${SHELL} /home/radhe/Downloads/systemc-2.3.3/config/missing aclocal-1.14'
AMDEPBACKSLASH=''
AMDEP_FALSE=''
AMDEP_TRUE=''
AMTAR='$${TAR-tar}'
AM_BACKSLASH='\'
AM_DEFAULT_V='0'
AM_DEFAULT_VERBOSITY='0'
AM_V='0'
AR=''
AUTOCONF='${SHELL} /home/radhe/Downloads/systemc-2.3.3/config/missing autoconf'
AUTOHEADER='${SHELL} /home/radhe/Downloads/systemc-2.3.3/config/missing autoheader'
AUTOMAKE='${SHELL} /home/radhe/Downloads/systemc-2.3.3/config/missing automake-1.14'
AWK='mawk'
CC=''
CCAS=''
CCASDEPMODE=''
CCASFLAGS=''
CCDEPMODE=''
CFLAGS=''
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS=''
CXX='g++'
CXXCPP=''
CXXDEPMODE=''
CXXFLAGS=''
CYGPATH_W='echo'
DEBUG_CXXFLAGS=''
DEFS=''
DEPDIR=''
DISABLE_ASYNC_UPDATES_FALSE=''
DISABLE_ASYNC_UPDATES_TRUE=''
DISABLE_VCD_SCOPES_FALSE=''
DISABLE_VCD_SCOPES_TRUE=''
DLLTOOL=''
DSYMUTIL=''
DUMPBIN=''
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
ENABLE_CALLBACKS_FALSE=''
ENABLE_CALLBACKS_TRACING_FALSE=''
ENABLE_CALLBACKS_TRACING_TRUE=''
ENABLE_CALLBACKS_TRUE=''
EXEEXT=''
EXPLICIT_LPTHREAD=''
EXTRA_ASFLAGS=''
EXTRA_CFLAGS=''
EXTRA_CXXFLAGS=''
EXTRA_LDFLAGS=''
FGREP=''
GREP=''
INSTALL_DATA='${INSTALL} -m 644'
INSTALL_PROGRAM='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_SCRIPT='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_STRIP_PROGRAM='$(install_sh) -c -s'
LD=''
LDFLAGS=''
LDFLAG_RPATH=''
LIBCONFIG_DEFINES=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=''
LIBTOOL=''
LIB_ARCH_SUFFIX=''
LIPO=''
LN_S=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
MAKEINFO='${SHELL} /home/radhe/Downloads/systemc-2.3.3/config/missing makeinfo'
MANIFEST_TOOL=''
MKDIR_P='/usr/bin/mkdir -p'
NM=''
NMEDIT=''
OBJDUMP=''
OBJEXT=''
OPT_CXXFLAGS=''
OTOOL64=''
OTOOL=''
PACKAGE='systemc'
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT='http://forums.accellera.org/forum/9-systemc/'
PACKAGE_NAME='SystemC'
PACKAGE_STRING='SystemC 2.3.3'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='systemc'
PACKAGE_URL='http://accellera.org/'
PACKAGE_VERSION='2.3.3'
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
PKGCONFIG_CFLAGS=''
PKGCONFIG_DEFINES=''
PKGCONFIG_LDPRIV=''
PTHREAD_CC=''
PTHREAD_CFLAGS=''
PTHREAD_LIBS=''
QT_ARCH=''
QT_ARCH_AARCH64_FALSE=''
QT_ARCH_AARCH64_TRUE=''
QT_ARCH_HPPA_FALSE=''
QT_ARCH_HPPA_TRUE=''
QT_ARCH_POWERPC_MACOSX_FALSE=''
QT_ARCH_POWERPC_MACOSX_TRUE=''
QT_ARCH_SPARC_FALSE=''
QT_ARCH_SPARC_TRUE=''
QT_ARCH_X86_64_FALSE=''
QT_ARCH_X86_64_TRUE=''
QT_ARCH_X86_FALSE=''
QT_ARCH_X86_TRUE=''
RANLIB=''
SED=''
SEPARATE_BUILD_TREE_FALSE=''
SEPARATE_BUILD_TREE_TRUE=''
SEPARATE_INSTALL_TREE_FALSE=''
SEPARATE_INSTALL_TREE_TRUE=''
SET_MAKE='MAKE=make'
SHELL='/bin/bash'
STRIP=''
TARGET_ARCH=''
TLM_PACKAGE_VERSION='2.0.5'
USES_PTHREADS_LIB_FALSE=''
USES_PTHREADS_LIB_TRUE=''
VERSION='2.3.3'
WANT_DEBUG_FALSE=''
WANT_DEBUG_TRUE=''
WANT_OPTIMIZE_FALSE=''
WANT_OPTIMIZE_TRUE=''
WANT_PTHREADS_THREADS_FALSE=''
WANT_PTHREADS_THREADS_TRUE=''
WANT_QT_THREADS_FALSE=''
WANT_QT_THREADS_TRUE=''
ac_ct_AR=''
ac_ct_CC=''
ac_ct_CXX=''
ac_ct_DUMPBIN=''
am__EXEEXT_FALSE=''
am__EXEEXT_TRUE=''
am__fastdepCCAS_FALSE=''
am__fastdepCCAS_TRUE=''
am__fastdepCC_FALSE=''
am__fastdepCC_TRUE=''
am__fastdepCXX_FALSE=''
am__fastdepCXX_TRUE=''
am__include=''
am__isrc=''
am__leading_dot='.'
am__nodep=''
am__quote=''
am__tar='tar --format=posix -chf - "$$tardir"'
am__untar='tar -xf -'
ax_pthread_config=''
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build='x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
build_alias=''
build_cpu='x86_64'
build_os='linux-gnu'
build_vendor='unknown'
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
examplesdir=''
exec_prefix='NONE'
host='x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
host_alias=''
host_cpu='x86_64'
host_os='linux-gnu'
host_vendor='unknown'
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
install_sh='${SHELL} /home/radhe/Downloads/systemc-2.3.3/config/install-sh'
libarchdir=''
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
mkdir_p='$(MKDIR_P)'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='NONE'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
rootdocdir=''
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target='x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
target_alias=''
target_cpu='x86_64'
target_os='linux-gnu'
target_vendor='unknown'

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME "SystemC"
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME "systemc"
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "2.3.3"
#define PACKAGE_STRING "SystemC 2.3.3"
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "http://forums.accellera.org/forum/9-systemc/"
#define PACKAGE_URL "http://accellera.org/"

configure: exit 77```
My system details :
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
Kernel :Linux 5.4.0-47-generic

Thank you for reading
````

Comment: The most obvious thing is that you don't appear to have a C++ compiler installed on your system - try installing the `build-essential` package and then running `./configure` again

Comment: Thank you, its working. I thought i would be C++ complier but didnt know how to do that. Also, was not aware about build-essential.